# Session sets the value successfully but gets null in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session

I am developing an MVC 5 application and I have a specific Controller for Session variables in my application which has 6 sessions, and all are working fine. Now I wanted to use another session, so I have declared it in my Session controller as follows:

```
public int tempResult
{
     get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempResult"]); }
     set { Session["tempResult"] = value; }
}
```

Now I have a Controller A which inherits from Session Controller and it is setting the session variable tempResult in method as:

```
[HttPPost]
public JsonResult COAcodelength(MST m)
{       
     var s = (from sets in db.ABCs where sets.name == "Name" && sets.pre.ToString() == m.house select sets.Id).Single().ToString();
     tempResult = Convert.ToInt32(s);
}
```

Now Controller B which also inherits from Session Controller is calling a method of Controller A and in that method I am trying to access the session value of tempResult as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult New([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,House,Number")] MST tr)
{    
    tr.Name = r.Ccode(tr); // r is the instance of Controller A
    db.MSTs.Add(tr);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return Json(tr);
}
```

And the **Ccode** method in Controller A is as:

```
public string Ccode (MST tr)
{
    int q = tempResult;
    tr.Name = q.ToString() + tr.House;
    return tr.Name; 
}
```

So, when Ccode method in Controller A tries to get the value of **tempResult** it returns null with Object reference error.

What could be the possible problem?

Comment: If `tempResult` is null `Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempResult"]);` will throw an error. You should check if `Session["tempResult"] == null` first.

Comment: Why are you using so many session? there are another ways available. session could expire any time, every time you need to check session is null or not. you can use model instead

Comment: I have got it working around by getting the value of tempResult in Controller B. I just want to know that why it is null in Controller A, when both A,B controllers are inherited from Session

Comment: @Arvaan, can you suggest some other potential ways?

Comment: Maybe that property is specific for that page instance only, session is available in all pages once set, have u tried explicitly calling it in your another controller like this? `int sessionValue = Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempResult"]);`. Anyway you are sure that the session value will not change in another controller.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert null to int 32, which meant that if your tempResult can be null, you should use it like this:

```
public int? tempResult
{
     get { return Convert.ToInt32(Session["tempResult"]); }
     set { Session["tempResult"] = value; }
}
```

Which will then allow the integer variable to accept null.

`int?` meaning the integer variable can be nullable.

Comment: ok. Fine... But I want to know Why the session is null even when the controller is inheriting from Session

Comment: You will need to debug it here. It seems that for some reason Ccode is returning NULL, meaning that one or more of your variables is not being assigned properly.